# Rotate wind rose icon with JavaScript based on JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, openweathermap

[Sandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-glitter-heg83?file=/index.html)

I'm trying to rotate a static compass icon (called [`towards-0-deg` / f0b1](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/)) to reflect the wind direction.

I tried `windRose = iconRotate.rotate(data.weather.deg);` and later `` windElement.innerHTML = ` ${windRose.rotate(data.weather.deg)}` + `${weather.wind} km/h`; `` but I get: **Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: iconRotate is not defined**.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your code iconRotate is indeed undefined yet, maybe you need to initialize this new variable with the  _towards-0-deg glyph. Take into account that in order to use transformations (rotatate) from css the icon should not be inline (but inline-block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it like so:

```
      weather.rose = function(){
    $(".wi-wind").addClass("from-" + windDirection + "-deg")
    setTimeout(function (){
      $("#roseIcon").removeClass();
      setTimeout(function () { 
      $("#roseIcon").addClass(`wi` +` `+ `wi-wind` +` `+ `from-` + windDirection + `-deg`)}, 1000)
    },920000)
  };
```